# Listview - Capture text from dynamically created textbox on Update

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a database and a bound Listview with dynamically created controls.  I have been attempting to find a way to capture the new value using markup as

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataKeyNames="ID" OnItemUpdating="ListView1_ItemUpdating">
```

and code behind as

```
Protected Sub ListView1_ItemUpdating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewUpdateEventArgs) Handles ListView1.ItemUpdating
    Dim capString As String = String.Empty
    capString = e.NewValues
 End Sub
```

This fails with the error *Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary' to type 'System.String'*

I'm hoping someone could help me identify either a better way to accomplish capturing this data, or if it is possible to cast this data and how to do it in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Dim capString As String = String.Empty 
capString = e.NewValues(1) As String
```

Substitute 1 with an appropriate index for your capString.

Comment: The index was missing, thank you for pointing it out.  Problem solved!